# Not able to compile simple project in Goland

Tags: go, module, compiler-errors, go-gin, goland

While executing a very simple project in Goland IDE, I see following errors. Tried setting GO111MODULE=on/off/auto.. Didn't make any difference!! Any idea?

Logs:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go #gosetup

GOPATH=/Users/<uid>/Documents/workspace/<ws_name> #gosetup
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o /private/var/folders/jn/kjwpzfrx5f98w9nrkzkw48040000gn/T/___go_build_main_go /Users/<uid>/Documents/workspace/<project>/src/github.com/<github_id>/users-api/main.go #gosetup

main.go:4:2: no required module provides package github.com/<github_id>/users-api/app: working directory is not part of a module

Compilation finished with exit code 1
```

NOTE: uid, github_id, ws_name etc are masks for actual ids

Comment: Do you have a go.mod file in your work directory? Make sure you run: go mod init <projectName> before trying to go build

Comment: Please read and stick to the first few documents in https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started where it is explained how to set up a module and build Go code. Note that setting GOROOT was never needed and is not needed and just looks fhishy.

Comment: What Go version are you using?

Comment: All this mess was created because of IDE. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing `go mod init <your project name>`

Then execute `go mod tidy`